# shortest and longest city name

Tags: sql, oracle

Query the two cities in STATION with the shortest and longest CITY names, as well as their respective lengths (i.e.: number of characters in the name). If there is more than one smallest or largest city, choose the one that comes first when ordered alphabetically.

May i please know answer to this question?

```
  SELECT CITY,
         LENGTH(CITY)
    FROM STATION
ORDER BY CITY ASC
   FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY ;
```

why is this query not working for fetch shortest length city?

Comment: It's not working because you are ordering by `city` when you probably meant to order by `length(city)`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT s.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY LENGTH(CITY), CITY) rn_first,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY LENGTH(CITY) DESC, CITY) rn_last
    FROM STATION s
)

SELECT CITY, LENGTH(CITY) AS CITY_LENGTH
FROM cte
WHERE 1 IN (rn_first, rn_last)
ORDER BY LENGTH(CITY);
```

This would generate a two record result set, with the shortest city name appearing first, and the longest, last.

Comment: yup I did this using row_number  on hacker rank.Oracle accepts fetch first 1 rows only also but this didn't work on hackerrank.

Answer (score 0):

My favorite way to do this in Oracle uses the `keep` keyword:

```
select min(city) keep (dense_rank first order by length(city) asc) as shortest_city,
       min(city) keep (dense_rank first order by length(city) desc) as longest_city,
       min(length(city)) as min_len,
       max(length(city)) as max_len
from station;
```

In my experience, `keep` has very good performance, so I wouldn't be surprised if this had the best performance on large data.

Comment: I don't understand.  Why would city name be missing?

Answer (score 0):

For MS SQL Server, Solution will be as follow.

```
Declare @Small int
Declare @Large int
select @Small = Min(Len(CITY )) from STATION 
select @Large = Max(Len(CITY )) from STATION
;with cte1 as(
select Top 1 CITY  as SmallestCity,Len(CITY ) as Minimumlength from STATION  where Len(CITY ) = @Small Order by CITY  Asc
),
cte2 as(
select Top 1 CITY  as LargestCity,Len(CITY ) as MaximumLength from STATION  where Len(CITY ) = @Large Order by CITY  Asc 
)
select * from cte1
union
select * from cte2
```

Its out put look like this,
[Out put of query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOWFg.png)

Answer (score 0):

The code I have written works for Microsoft SQL Server

```
select city, len(city) from station where len(city) = (select max(len(city)) from station);
```

```
select city, len(city) from station where len(city) = (select min(len(city)) from station) order by city desc offset 2 rows
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```html
(select city, length(city) from station order by length(city), city Limit 1)
union all
(select city, length(city) from station order by length(city) DESC, city Limit 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from (
    select min(city) city_name, length(city) size 
      from station group by length(city)) as temp 
     where temp.size = (
             select min(length(city))
               from station)
        or temp.size = (
             select max(length(city))
               from station)
;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with hello AS 
(
  select city, LENGTH(CITY) as ul from STATION
)
select city, Max(ul) from hello
UNION all
select city, Min(ul) from hello
```

Answer (score 0):

#MySQL#
(select city, length(city) from station order by length(city), city Limit 1)
union all
(select city, length(city) from station order by length(city) DESC, city Limit 1);

#oracle#
(Select * from (Select City,Length(City) from station
Order by Length(City) , City)  WHERE ROWNUM <= 1)
Union all
(Select * from (Select City,Length(City) from station
Order by Length(City) Desc , City)  WHERE ROWNUM <= 1);

Answer (score -1):

You need to modify your `ORDER BY`:

```sql
SELECT CITY, LENGTH(CITY)
FROM STATION
ORDER BY LENGTH(CITY) DESC, CITY
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY ;
```

This will give the answer for the longest name.  For the shortest name, just change the `ORDER BY` to use `ASC` for `LENGTH(CITY)`.

Comment: The requirement is asking for _two_ city names, not just one.

Comment: I did read that part, but the user did not specify it had to be in one query.  Your answer takes care of that, though.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT CITY,
       LENGTH(CITY) as length
  FROM CITY
 ORDER BY length ASC limit 1;
```

Comment: `limit` option for `ORDER` Clause doesn't exist in Oracle.

Comment: While this answer may be correct. Code only answers are rarely helpful. Please comment your code and provide an explanation for how this code solves the problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT top 1 City,LEN(City) as Citylength into #tmp
FROM STATION
WHERE LEN(City)=(SELECT MIN(LEN(City)) FROM STATION )
order by City asc

SELECT top 1 City,LEN(City) as Citylength into #tmp1
FROM STATION
WHERE LEN(City)=(SELECT MAX(LEN(City)) FROM STATION )
order by City

select * from #tmp
union
select * from #tmp1
```

Answer (score -1):

**Here is the most straightforward answer**
Hint: If you wanna try there won't be any aggregation or subquery just go with the length operator and limit rows,
moreover, this is a query for MySQL but it can run elsewhere too with a little tweak and changes:-

FYI this is a hackerank question------

```
SELECT CITY, LENGTH(CITY)
FROM STATION
ORDER BY LENGTH(CITY)ASC, CITY ASC
LIMIT 1;

SELECT CITY, LENGTH(CITY)
FROM STATION
ORDER BY LENGTH(CITY)DESC, CITY DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

#sql #hackerrank #easy

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT CITY,LENGTH(CITY)

FROM STATION

WHERE LENGTH(CITY) IN  (SELECT min(LENGTH(CITY))
                                    
                                       FROM  STATION
                                )
AND ROWNUM <= 1

UNION 

SELECT CITY,LENGTH(CITY)

FROM  STATION 
WHERE LENGTH(CITY) IN  (SELECT max(LENGTH(CITY))
                                    
                                   FROM  STATION )
AND ROWNUM <= 1

ORDER BY CITY ASC;
```